# How to skip the order confirmation page with ActiveMerchant and PayPal Express

Tags: paypal, activemerchant

Regarding to the PayPal docs it's possible to skip the order confirmation page and let the customer pay on PayPal. To do so, the parameter "**useraction**" must be set to "**commit**". How can this be done with ActiveMerchants **setup_purchase** method?

[PayPal - Customizing Express Checkout](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECCustomizing)

Answer (score 8):

Got it. Just set the review parameter in the **redirect_url_for** method to false. Example:

```
EXPRESS_GATEWAY.redirect_url_for(response.token, review: false)
```